# USB flash drive doesn't work properly after making it bootable

Tags: usb-flash-drive, ntfs, windows-11, usb-storage, fat32

I burned Raspbian buster lite on my USB drive.

Now I can only use it as storage.
I can see the USB flash drive and I can copy on it, but it doesn't accept any burning tool anymore.

What I have tried:

- Formatting through Rufus
- partition master
- diskmngt.msc
- disk part
- I deep formatted and repaired the USB, Nothing worked
- I tried NTFS and Fat32

Any suggestions?

Note: my USB flash drive is aKingston Data Traveler 100 G3 32GB

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't accept any burning tool"? (USB drives don't really _have_ a burn operation; these tools literally do the same kind of sector writes as copying a file, so it's pretty unlikely for one to work but not the other.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem,
It seems windows 11 blocked all boot makers programs,
**To solve this Just Turn OFF windows security live**